# How to position an SVG canvas

Tags: html, css, svg

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to position an SVG element on a page. I spent a good hour reading Sara Soueidan tutorial on positioning the inner contents of an SVG element inside the viewport of the SVG, but I cannot find anywhere how you would position the viewport on the page. I tried wrapping my SVG inside a div and floating the div (to no avail):

```
<div id="svg-left">
    <svg id="angle-left" class="angle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon points="352,115.4 331.3,96 160,256 331.3,416 352,396.7 201.5,256 "/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This seems like such a simple concept, but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position an `<svg>` element the same as any other HTML element.  You can float them, use absolute positioning, etc.

Here's a demo:

```css
#angle-left
{
    float: right;
}

#angle-left2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="angle-left" class="angle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <polygon points="352,115.4 331.3,96 160,256 331.3,416 352,396.7 201.5,256 "/>
</svg>

<svg id="angle-left2" class="angle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <polygon points="352,115.4 331.3,96 160,256 331.3,416 352,396.7 201.5,256 "/>
</svg>
```

(I reduced the on screen size of the SVGs to make the positioning more obvious).